# How to start for-loop from the starting iteration of list after matching the condition using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, for-loop, recursion

Trying to achieve the below task:

```
for element in list:
    if condition is true:
        remove element from list
        start the for loop again with element removed list
```

To achieve this i tried like,

```
def func(list, p1, p2):
    for element in list:
        if condition is true:
            new_list = remove element from list
        func(new_list, p1, p2)
#Here p1, p2 are used in condition.
```

> I'm getting the error as maximum recursion depth is exceeded.

**Updated Complete Code:**

```
def winner(array, current_player, a, b):
    bob = alice = 0

    def winner_recursive(array, current_player, a, b):
        nonlocal bob, alice

        for cn in array:
            if cn % current_player == 0:
                array.remove(cn)

                if current_player == a:
                    bob += 1
                    current_player = b
                else:
                    alice += 1
                    current_player = a

                return winner_recursive(array, current_player, a, b)

    winner_recursive(array, current_player, a, b)
    if bob > alice:
        return 'BOB'
    elif bob < alice:
        return 'ALICE'
    else:
        if current_player == a:
            return 'ALICE'
        else:
            return 'BOB'

t = int(input())
for _ in range(t):
    N, a, b = map(int, input().split())
    arr = list(map(int, input().split()))

    cp = a
    arr.sort(reverse=True)
    print(winner(arr, cp, a, b))
```

**input to above code**

```
2
5 3 2
1 2 3 4 5
5 2 4
1 2 3 4 5
```

**Expected Output:**

```
ALICE
BOB
```

Can any one help me to achieve this through recursion or what is best pythonic way to do this task?

**Note:** Other similar SO questions, deals with range of number. Here, I'm trying with list in loop.

Comment: Shouldn't the recursive `func` call be *inside* the `if` clause?

Comment: You need to provide a base condition in order to exit recursive .

Comment: @meowgoesthedog- Yes, I tried that. But i'm not able to achieve the mentioned task. I'm searching for best pythonic way to do this.

Comment: Based on the link to the problem you posted in comments to my answer, I believe your solution needs to be rethought.  There is no reason to tally anything, the game outcome is determined by inability to continue.  There's logic missing as one player can remove multiple numbers according to the rules.  There's missing strategy as it would be to a player's advantage to remove a number that was a multiple of both their own number and the other player's -- though I'm not sure if the rules say if players know each other's lucky number.  But it does say 'play optimally' so does that implies such?

Comment: @cdlane- yes, you are right. I'm bit confused at 'play optimally' sentence. As I mentioned in your comments, with updated code in question. I am able to get right answer, but getting `runtime error (ZNEC)` and i think reason was same as stated by `ggorlen` in your comments. Can you please tell me the more pythonic  way to achieve this?

Comment: I wouldn't worry about whether your code is Pythonic or not. You need to formulate an algorithm beyond language features. I would close this question as an [x-y problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), sit down with some small examples of this bob/alice problem and try to work through them by hand until you develop a solution strategy.

Comment: @ggorlen- As I mentioned in you in below comment, that is my main problem. Literally, I'm trying hard to learn algorithmic approach to solve problems. Which is my main drawback. Hope, I will get better by practicing. You can please guide me some books or links. That will be great here!

Comment: If this problem is too difficult, try something easier, then build up to it. This is not a trivial problem where you can code up the game instructions and hit run. If you're searching the space exhaustively, you'll need to attempt *every possible removal for every player's turn*, which is insane [time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity) and won't scale beyond tiny inputs. This problem seems like a [nim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nim) problem, and I bet there is a mathematical solution.

Comment: @ggorlen- Thanks for your response, sharing thoughts and providing links. I will follow them to solve problems. I'm really happy to see skilled people like you in SO. As my background is not computer science, this are taking long time to understand and i need to more concentrate on algorithms. Thanks once again for correcting me :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should indent the function call, such that it doesn't *always* get triggered:

```
def func(list, p1, p2):
    for element in list:
        if condition:
            new_list = remove element from list
            func(new_list, p1, p2)
```

However, you can do without recursion:

```
while True:
    for element in list:
        if condition:
            list.remove(element)
            break
    else:
        break  # we didn't break out of the inner loop, so we're done
```

Comment: @L3viathan- I tried with recursive function. But, i'm not able to achieve, my mentioned task. I have pasted the complete code. Can you please check?

Comment: @shaikmoeed You're getting `None`, I presume? You need to return that function call, i.e. `return winner(arr, cp, a, b)`.

Comment: @L3viathan- Thanks for your response. I'm not getting right output after adding `return`. May be I need to find some other logic to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're having your recursive function `winner()` working on two different problems.  You need to extract just the recursive part:

```
def take_turn(array, a, b):
    global current_player

    for number in array:
        if number % current_player == 0:
            array.remove(number)

            if current_player == a:
                current_player = b
            else:
                current_player = a

            take_turn(array, a, b)

            break  # sub-optimal play

curent_player = None

t = int(input())

for _ in range(t):
    _, b, a = map(int, input().split())
    array = list(map(int, input().split()))

    current_player = b  # Bob plays first

    take_turn(array, a, b)

    # loser is the player stuck unable to make a move
    print('ALICE' if current_player == b else 'BOB')
```

This doesn't get the correct result, as it doesn't play optimally -- it simply gets the recursion working.  It may also fail if the array gets large enough, depending on how Python's recursion depth limit is set.

Comment: @cdlane- Thanks for your answer. Can you explain the purpose of `nonlocal` here. What if i define variables outside `def` and make it global in `def`. link is [https://www.codechef.com/JAN19B/problems/HP18]

Comment: Your code is O(n^2) and uses one recursive call for each element removal. The problem is, the input size is 200000 and you have 10 test cases to pass in 1 second, according to the link. It's helpful to state these requirements at the top of your question--even if you get this code working, you're going to have to dump it and move on to formulating a more optimal approach!

Comment: @ggorlen, the limitations you're discussing were unknown at the time I wrote my answer so I couldn't anticipate them.  The OP wanted a working recursive solution which is what I tried to outline.  I agree that recursion may be an issue but upping the recursion limit in Python may still get around this, I'm not sure yet.

Comment: Sorry, I should have @shaikmoeed with that comment. It wasn't directed to you!

Comment: @shaikmoeed, `nonlocal`  is explained in the [Nonlocal Variables in Python section of this website](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/global-local-nonlocal-variables#nonlocal-variables)

Comment: @ggorlen- you are right. I have made some changes to my code. while submitting the solution, getting `runtime error (NZEC)`. How can I handle that? Can you please explain me. I'm not good in algorithms. I just started studying algorithms. It will be great to listen some advice from you :-).

Comment: @cdlane- sry, for asking again. The edited code is not giving right result. Getting `runtime error (NZEC)`.

Comment: If you add a hyphen after your @name- it won't notify anyone. As I mentioned above, dump this code completely and start over. Brute force is not a workable solution for this problem. If you can't figure out an approach, there's no shame in that. Work on easier problems and build up your skills first.

Comment: @shaikmoeed, I copied and pasted the code from the page and it ran fine.  One possibility is you're running it under Python 2, in which case change the two calls to `input` to instead be `raw_input`.

Comment: @ggorlen, Okay, sure. Thanks for correcting. Yeah, sure. I will work on my skills first.

Comment: @cdlane, No, I'm running in python 3. I pasted your code and tried to submit. It throws runtime error(NZEC). Something may be missing, which I'm not able find out!

Comment: @shaikmoeed, you could try setting `sys.setrecursionlimit()` to some large value but I didn't get much past an array size of 30,000 with that approach -- no where near the 200,000 limit.  If the players pulled more than one number from the array on each turn, that would reduce the recursion stack requirements.

Comment: @cdlane, when I set to limit 30,000 or 200,000. I am getting `Time limit exceed` error.